# Positive Semidefinite Property from Eigen Values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ are Hermitian symmetric matrices.

Eigen values of $\mathbf{A}$ in ascending order are $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Similarly those of $\mathbf{B}$ (in ascending order) are $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $\lambda_i\geq\mu_i\quad\forall 1\leq i\leq n$, is $\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}$ positive semidefinite? If the given data are not enough, does the additional assumption $\mathbf{A}$ is positive semidefinite help?

P. S. I know the converse is true, but not sure about this. It's part of a power allocation problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: If you know that $AB = BA$, then I believe it is true since you can simultaneously diagonalize them, but otherwise, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick counterexample: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. Looks like the additional assumption doesn't help. Intuition is from just swapping eigenspaces.